# Pipe at the command line

Tags: windows-7, powershell

In the blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2007/07/09/grep-and-sed-with-powershell.aspx I found a replacement for sed implemented as PowerShell script. I don't want to depend on the installation of any 3rd party sed variant. Therefore I would use the solution from the link above:

```
SED-ish

cat somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "expression","replace"}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in this way

```
powershell cat somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "expression","replace"}
```

since the `|` is interpreted by cmd.exe. How do I make this nice PowerShell Script to a one-liner, used in a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Running PowerShell commands in a batch script

You can use the `-Command` parameter, like this:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "cat somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace 'expression\",\"replace\"}"
```

**Note** In the command string `"` needs to be escaped using `\"` (or replaced with `'`), and `%` has to be escaped with `%%`.

### Further reading

- [Running Windows PowerShell Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx)
- [More Powerful Ways to Launch Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff629472.aspx)
- [Batch files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
powershell -Command "cat somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace 'expression','replace'}"
```

Comment: `%` has to be escaped with `%%`.

Comment: @harper To clarify: it does work when run in a command prompt, but not when being executed in a batch script. Windows 7 / PowerShell 2.0.